# IOS reload view once method completes

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm working on an app that stores it's data in the cloud (parse). When I open the app it goes to the cloud and pull down the data. This takes a little time and while it's waiting the view has loaded. I want the view to load again after the new data has been downloaded and created. How would I do this?

Is there a command to reload a MasterView?

Answer (score 4):

Parse have completion blocks fro their fetch methods. you need to use on of them, and reload the view when the block return a success (error = nil) -

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
    // The find succeeded.
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];

     } else {
     // Log details of the failure
     NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
     }
 }];
```

Look here for more info -
[Parse Queries Docs](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries/iOS)

Comment: This makes sense, but fails in my code. I get the error "property 'tableView' not found on object of type 'MSMasterViewController'" any ideas?

Comment: Soory, my mistake. you wanted a view update and not a table view. Fixed my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Implement a method that is called upon completion of the download, from there, refresh your view.

```
- (void)downloadDidFinish
{
    [myViewNeedingToBeRefreshed setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

The `-setNeedsDisplay` (`UIView` method) will schedule your view to be refreshed, and any `Core Graphics` to be redrawn.